# Arrange data in tables?

Tags: html, codeigniter, foreach, html-table, codeigniter-3

I retrieve the data from the database and tried to implement them in the table, but now I don't know how to arrange them in the table. My view is:

```
<?php include('inc/header.php');?>

<div class="main">

<table>

    <thead>
            <tr>ID:</tr>
            <th>Name:</th>

</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>

        <?php foreach ($view as $row) :?>

            <?php $i = 1;?>
            <?php echo "<td>".$row->audio."</td>";?>
            <?php echo $i++;?>
            <?php endforeach;?>


    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>


</div>
<?php include('inc/footer.php');?>
```

I just want to make the place id increase from one to the as many records and arrange them into one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach loop should be like this

```
<tbody>
    <?php 
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($view as $row)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row->audio."</td>";
        $i++;
        echo "</tr>";
    }
   ?>
</tbody>
```

And `<thead>` should be

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID:</th>
        <th>Name:</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: pleasure is all mine.

Comment: is my declaration of the table head is correct because id is above the name.@spartan

Comment: @sudeepacharya Its should be both `<th>` not `<tr>`

Comment: @sudeepacharya check the edit now. May be its clear now

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php $i = 1;?>
<?php foreach ($view as $row) :?>
<tr>
            <?php echo "<td>".$i++."</td>";?>
            <?php echo "<td>".$row->audio."</td>";?>

 </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: [`<td>`](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38635723/1) for id is missing

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code**

```
  <?php
  $i=1;
  foreach ($view as $row) 
  {

 ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->audio;?></td>        
     </tr>
    <?php 
    $i++;
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<?php
  $i=0;//place the initial value outside the loop
  foreach ($view as $row) 
  {
  $i++;//increment the value
 ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i;//display the value ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->audio;?></td>        
     </tr>
    <?php 

    } ?>
```